# Error ImportError: No module named 'encodings' in virtual environment using pyenv

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to publish the site created by Django using apache.
The settings of the server are as follows.

・ CentOS 7.2
・ Python 3.6
・ Django 2.0
・ apache 2.4

I am preparing a virtual environment using pyenv as follows.

```
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
…
pyenv install anaconda3-5.1.0
pyenv rehash
pyenv global anaconda3-5.1.0
…
yum install httpd httpd-devel
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
….
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.5.14.tar.gz
tar -zxvf 4.5.14.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-4.5.14/
./configure --with-python=/home/username/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/bin/python
make
sudo make install
…
```

■ httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName xxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

WSGIScriptReloading On
WSGIDaemonProcess xxx python-path=/home/username/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages python-home=/home/username/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0
WSGIProcessGroup xxx
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/xxx/xxx/wsgi.py

<Directory "/xxx/">
Order deny,allow
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The following error will occur with this setting.

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Setting chmod should be fine. What other reasons can be considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 4.5.14 of mod_wsgi is old, use the latest version.

Preferable to install it using `pip install mod_wsgi` to your Python installation of virtual environment as that ensures correct Python shared library is picked up, which when it doesn't occur, can cause this problem.

Then run `mod_wsgi-express module-config` to show the config lines to add to Apache to load mod_wsgi. This may include a `LoadFile` line as well to further enforce correct Python library is used, which for Anaconda Python is important.

Then use the config:

```
# I really hope you haven't thrown away your complete Apache
# config file. This should already be defined as part of the
# default Apache config file.

NameVirtualHost *:80

# Put here the output of running mod_wsgi-express module-config.

# Also turn of embedded mode using the following since using
# daemon mode.

WSGIRestrictEmbedded on


# This may not actually be required. Only needed on some RHEL
# and CentOS systems.

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName xxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

WSGIScriptReloading On

# The python-path wasn't needed. BTW, don't recommend using pyenv
# if using PSF Python as their default formula for building Python
# from source code doesn't create a shared library so it will not
# work with mod_wsgi. Anaconda Python is probably okay as it would
# use binary distro.

# Ensure python-home is what is value of sys.prefix for Python.

WSGIDaemonProcess xxx python-home=/home/username/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0

WSGIProcessGroup xxx

# Also force main interpreter if have only one app.

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/xxx/xxx/wsgi.py

# Apache 2.4 should use 'Require all granted'.

# The ``/xxx`` path should match full absolute directory of WSGI
# script file used in ``WSGIScriptAlias``, so not right here.

<Directory "/xxx/">
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

BTW, bad idea to put your Python source code under the same directory as `DocumentRoot` has. If you comment out `WSGIScriptAlias`, people can download your code.

Comment: BTW, you can also drop ``WSGIScriptReloading On`` as that is the default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/virtualenv/
```

to httpd.conf

https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html